LSTM forecasting model highly dependent on random seed: how to tame this effect?
I have a time series forecasting binary classification model made up of several layers of LSTM or GRU cells.  The training is early stopped in a given validation set.
The thing is my results vary tremendously with the modification of the random seeds (I utilize the deterministic switch in TensorFlow). I suppose this is because of the random state initialization.
In an effort to mitigate this effect and reduce variability, I have trained an ensemble of models with different seeds and pool the predicted probabilities using the some rule (median seems to work best). This ensemble is trained with a set of hyperparameters that I have previously obtained through CV search (on single models, not ensembles).
Now, my questions:

Does my ensemble approach make any sense at all?

Among the models in the ensemble, there is always (as could be expected) one or two models which perform better on validation and/or test sets than the ensemble itself. Instead of the ensemble, could I simply find the random seed which seems to work best and deem this the best agnostic model? In my head this seems to be in danger of some sort of ''''overfitting'''' the randomness to the specific test sets, but it may also just be a way to find the best initial states for the optimization problem.

In general, how would you deal with this problem?


I appreciate any insights.
